# Pandas transformation really slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I been trying to transform python pandas to from one representation to another but is really slow:

My current dataframe is like:

```
Column0, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 10... 
   p1        1           2         8          3
   p2        2           4         9          6

Column0,   sample,       Exp
   p1       Column 1      1 
   p1       Column 2      2
   p1       Column 3      8
   p1       Column 10     3
   p2       Column 1      2 
   .           .          .
   .           .          .
```

I use the `iterrows` inserting into a new dataframe but is really slow. The Column 1,2 is not fixed but I have a collection with all the names.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? _I use the `iterrows`_ Don't! `iterrows()` is sluggish, and often times there are more idiomatic alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `melt`,

generally looping is discouraged in pandas unless there is no other option or you have a justifiable usecase.

```
d = """Column0, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 10 
   p1,        1,           2,         8,          3
   p2,        2,           4,         9,          6"""


from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep=',')

df2 = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Column0'],var_name='Sample',value_name='Exp')

print(df2)

  Column0       Sample  Exp
0      p1     Column 1    1
1      p2     Column 1    2
2      p1     Column 2    2
3      p2     Column 2    4
4      p1     Column 3    8
5      p2     Column 3    9
6      p1   Column 10     3
7      p2   Column 10     6
```

## Chaining Operations

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Column0'],var_name='Sample',value_name='Exp').rename(
             columns = {'Column0' : 'NewCol',...})
```

Comment: Hi @Datanovice if `Column 1, 2, 3` (like `Column0, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 10, another column, another column2`) has other columns after that I don't want to transform what can I do?

Comment: you can add them `id_vars` `id_vars=['Column0','ColumnX','ColumnY']` @ypriverol

Comment: If I want to rename Column1, Colum2, etc can I do it in the same melt operation.?

Comment: do you know how to do unmelt?

Comment: @ypriverol asks new question please